# Remove specific object instances from list

Tags: python, list, object

As a Python newbie, I am really struggling to find a nice and performant way to remove objects from a list, if another object in this list has the same attribute value for some attributes, but a bigger value for another attribute value.

I thought about using the `__eq__(self, other)` and `set()` to get the job done, e.g.:

```python
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, ViewData):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.session_id == other.session_id \
                and self.user_id == other.user_id \
                and self.course_id == other.course_id \
                and self.video_id == other.video_id \
                and self.locale == other.locale \
                and self.watched_percentage >= other.watched_percentage
```

Is there a better and more pythonic way to do it?

Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: overloading the operators is a way to solve it, but if it is always a greater than expression, why not overload `__gt__`?

Comment: Equality should be symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Build a dict with `session_id, ..., locale` as key and a list of its objects as value. Then from each key's list, pick the maximum by `watched_percentage`.

Or keep track of each key's maximum object on the fly.